# ACE_RCSID is not found in ACE 6.1

Tags: c++, ace

ACE_RCSID is a function which is available in ACE5.5 for some loggin purpose. This is not present in ACE 6.1, is there any other equivalent function is available in ACE 6.1 similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that support has been removed and we don't have something similar again in ACE.

Comment: May I know why it has been removed and from which version it has been removed?

Comment: It was coming from the old cvs days and we didn't see any reason why we should keep it. Not sure when it got removed, check the NEWS and ChangeLog files as part of the distribution. Maybe if you can share exactly for what you used it, we can recommend a replacement, but a better place to ask is the ace-users mailing list